# Reshape (M, N, 3) numpy array to (M*N, 3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an RGB (or HSV) image represented by an (M, N, 3) numpy array wherein each dimension (`[x, y, 0]` or `[x, y, 1]`) represents a color channel value at a specific pixel. I want to reshape the array to (M*N, 3) where the color channels are combined (`[R1, G1, B1], [R2, G2, B2]`...) into a flat list (is that the correct terminology in this case?). I understand that one must use the reshape function, but I'm having difficulty understanding *how* to use the function. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is an example of what I would like to happen.

Input: (640 x 640 x 3) array representative of image where `[40, 40, 1]` would be the G value for a specific pixel. I want to take all 3 color channels and combine them into the following output.

Output: `([R, G, B], [R, G, B], [R, G, B]...)`

Comment: Can you show some example input and output?

Comment: Are you sure that you want (M, 3) and not (M, N)?

Comment: @Dataman yes. I want to flatten the image array so that I can pass it to an SVM. I want a flat list of RGB values

Comment: Wouldnt you need an (MxN, 3) matrix? you would need a single value for each coordinate, assuming that M and N are your dimensional sizes. Reshapes should only work if the matrix before and after have the same amount of elements.

Comment: Something like `arr.reshape(-1,3)` probably.

Comment: *"I want to reshape the array to (M, 3) ..."*  I assume you actually mean `(M*N, 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `img` is your array, you can use `img.reshape(-1, 3)`.

For example,

```
In [50]: img.shape
Out[50]: (5, 2, 3)

In [51]: img
Out[51]: 
array([[[2, 0, 4],
        [1, 4, 3]],

       [[2, 1, 4],
        [3, 2, 2]],

       [[2, 4, 1],
        [4, 0, 2]],

       [[1, 4, 2],
        [3, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 2, 1],
        [2, 1, 0]]])


In [53]: x = img.reshape(-1, 3)

In [54]: x.shape
Out[54]: (10, 3)

In [55]: x
Out[55]: 
array([[2, 0, 4],
       [1, 4, 3],
       [2, 1, 4],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [2, 4, 1],
       [4, 0, 2],
       [1, 4, 2],
       [3, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion. I meant M*N instead of just M. This is perfect

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then, I would do something like this:

```
## loading the image...
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
import matplotlib.image as mpimg  
image = mpimg.imread("my_image.jpg")  

## extracting R, G, B and flatten them separately and then make
## an array out of them. 
res = np.transpose(np.array([image[...,0].flatten(), image[...,1].flatten(), image[...,2].flatten()]))
```

This might not be the most elegant way, but it will work. Actually, this do not give `(M, 3)` but it give `(MxN, 3)`. This should be actually desired, because with `(M, 3)` you are loosing some data!